# how to refactor the duplicate code?

Tags: java, refactoring, duplicates

i know the duplicate is smell

but how to refactor the code?

```
public List<HighWay> updateAllNewHighWays(HighWayRepository repository)
            throws IOException {
        List<HighWay> highWays = new ArrayList<HighWay>();
        for (RoadCode code : RoadCode.values()) {
            try {
                pageParam.setRoadName(code);
                highWays.addAll(getAndSaveNewHighWay(repository));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                IOException exception = dealException(e, code);
                throw exception;
            }
        }
        return highWays;
    }

    public List<HighWay> getAllNewHighWays(HighWayRepository repository)
            throws IOException {
        List<HighWay> highWays = new ArrayList<HighWay>();
        for (RoadCode code : RoadCode.values()) {
            try {
                pageParam.setRoadName(code);
                highWays.addAll(getNewHighWay(repository));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                IOException exception = dealException(e, code);
                throw exception;
            }
        }
        return highWays;
    }
```

Comment: how about moving duplicating code to a separate method?

Comment: yes,but the loop how to move?and getAndSaveNewHighWay and getNewHighWay how to refer?

Comment: this is the actual problem: getAndSaveNewHighWay. what does that do anyway? gets the list and adds a new blank one?

Comment: ok, this code is bad for many reasons, not only for code duplication. as far as I see this two methods are the same except call inside a loop. this call takes as argument parameter of enclosing method, and, if this code was written in immutable manner, I would be pretty sure that `getAndSaveNewHighWay(repository)` and `getNewHighWay(repository)` could be moved to the beggining of this methods and other code could be moved to separate method. but I guess that `pageParam.setRoadName(code);` has a certain side-effect on this method calls.

Comment: shortly, refactoring of this code should be started not with removing duplicating code, but with rewriting underlying methods

Comment: tanks very much， can i make the method as arguments？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only part that changes is the inside of a loop, you can refactor out the looping part any only have the part inside the loop change.

If you use Java 8 you can pass in the `getAndSaveNewHighWay(repository)` or `getNewHighWay(repository)` as method a method reference as a `Function<HighWayRepository, List<HighWay>>` implementation

```
public List<HighWay> handleHighways(HighWayRepository repository, Function<HighWayRepository, List<HighWay>> function){
  List<HighWay> highWays = new ArrayList<HighWay>();
        for (RoadCode code : RoadCode.values()) {
            try {

                pageParam.setRoadName(code);
                //call our method 
                highWays.addAll(function.apply(repository));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                IOException exception = dealException(e, code);
                throw exception;
            }
        }
        return highWays;
}
```

Then in your calling code:

```
 List<HighWay> highways = handleHighways(repository, MyClass::getAndSaveNewHighWay);
```

or

```
List<HighWay> highways = handleHighways(repository, MyClass::getNewHighWay);
```

Without Java 8, you can achieve something similar by making your own interface that has a method that takes a `HighWayRepository` and return a `List<HighWay>` and then write 2 different implementations

Answer (score 0):

### In order to remove duplication I used next algorithm:

1. Make sure you have tests which verify such functionality works or not (before refactoring all your tests should be running green)
2. Copy and paste duplicated logic into a new method (e.g. tobeReused, later you can rename it to a better one)
3. Parametrize what changes using lambdas (Java supports next types of lambdas: Runnable, Consumer, Predicate, Function)
4. Rename method in 1. To a better name. In order not to get stuck in **analysis-paralysis**, it is a good idea to rename things after you understand it.

---

1. A good test suite should

   1. Focus on behavioral tests
   2. Cover positive and negative scenarios
   3. Cover edge cases
   4. Cover exceptions
   5. Tests names should describe *what* is going to be tested not *how*
   6. Each test should be formatted following Given-When-Then or Arrange-Act-Assert.

   Example code structure for a possible test suite:

   ```
   public class HighwaysTest {
     //Repository is valid
     @Test
     public void whenHighWayRepositoryIsValidThenHighWaysShouldBeSaved() {
     }

     //Repository is invalid
     @Test
     public void whenHighWayRepositoryIsInvalidThenHighWaysShouldBeSaved() {
     }

     //Wrong road code
     @Test
     public void whenRoadCodeIsInvalidThenPageParamIsNotUpdated() {
     }

     //Function getAndSaveNewHighWay fails
     @Test
     public void whenGetAndSaveNewHighWayFailsThenExceptionIsThrown() {

     }

     //Function getNewHighWay fails
     @Test
     public void whenGetNewHighWayFailsThenExceptionIsThrown() {

     }
   }
   ```
2. Copy and Paste duplicated logic into a new method

   ```
    private List<HighWay> tobeReused(HighWayRepository repository) throws IOException {
           List<HighWay> highWays = new ArrayList<HighWay>();
           for (RoadCode code : RoadCode.values()) {
               try {
                   pageParam.setRoadName(code);
                   highWays.addAll(getAndSaveNewHighWay(repository));
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   IOException exception = dealException(e, code);
                   throw exception;
               }
           }
           return highWays;
       }
   ```
3. Parametrize what changes using lambdas (in this case `Function<ParameterType, ReturnType>`):

   ```
       private <P extends  HighWayRepository, 
                R extends  Collection> List<HighWay> tobeReused(P repository, Function<P, R> lambda) throws IOException {
   List<HighWay> highWays = new ArrayList<HighWay>();
               for (RoadCode code : RoadCode.values()) {
                   try {
                       pageParam.setRoadName(code);
                       highWays.addAll(lambda.apply(repository));
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       IOException exception = dealException(e, code);
                       throw exception;
                   }
               }
               return highWays;
           }
   ```
4. As finding a good name can be tricky it is better to name things after you get a good grasp of the business domain. Then function `tobeReused` could be renamed to `updatePageParamAndReturnHighways`:

#### Your code will look like:

```
public List<HighWay> updateAllNewHighWays(HighWayRepository repository) throws IOException {
        Function<HighWayRepository, Collection> lambda = (repo) -> getAndSaveNewHighWay(repo);
        List<HighWay> highWays = updatePageParamAndReturnHighways(repository, lambda);
        return highWays;
    }

public List<HighWay> getAllNewHighWays(HighWayRepository repository) throws IOException {
        Function<HighWayRepository, Collection> lambda = (repo) -> getNewHighWay(repo);
        List<HighWay> highWays = updatePageParamAndReturnHighways(repository, lambda);
        return highWays;
    }
```

### Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)

You might want to consider to refactor your functions
`updateAllNewHighWays` and `getAllNewHighWays` as they have more than one responsibility (update `pageParam` and return highways).